# Dynamic json-eval expressions in WSO2 ESB 5

Tags: javascript, json, wso2-esb

I'm trying to process a JSONPayload using a dynamically generated json-eval to select a perticular hotel object. 
Below mentioned direct json-eval works fine.

**Direct json-eval expression :**

```
json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')])
```

I have tried beow like options but no any luck yet.

**TRY 1 :**

```
<property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'ALE1_LON'"/>
<property expression="fn:concat('$.content[?(@.hotelcode==',get-property('htlCode'),')]')" name="xpathExpr" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="json-eval({$ctx:xpathExpr})" name="hotelContet" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This uses the "`{$ctx:xpathExpr}`" as the JSON Path instead of "`$.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')]`".

**TRY 2 :**

```
<property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'ALE1_LON'"/>
<property expression="fn:concat('json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode==',get-property('htlCode'),')])')" name="hotelContet" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This stores "`json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')])`" to the hotelContet property without eveluating it.

**TRY 3 :**

```
<property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'ALE1_LON'"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode=={get-property('htlCode')})])" name="hotelContet" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This uses the "`$.content[?(@.hotelcode=={get-property('htlCode')})]`" as the JSON Path instead of "`$.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')]`".

**TRY 4 :**

```
<property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'ALE1_LON'"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.content[?(@.hotelcode=={$ctx.htlCode})])" name="hotelContet" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This uses the "`$.content[?(@.hotelcode=={$ctx.htlCode})]`" as the JSON Path instead of "`$.content[?(@.hotelcode=='ALE1_LON')]`".

**Json Payload :**

```
{
    "_id":"INV27_1112",
    "_rev":"5-876038bf65752ce4505e50baea6d5581",
    "content":[
        {
            "hotelcode":"AMB3_LON",
            "hotelname":"Ambassadors Bloomsbury"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALE1_LON",
            "hotelname":"Alexandra"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALO_LON",
            "hotelname":"Aloft London Excel"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note : I know that this can be done with Script / Class mediator. But I'm looking for a solution within the json-eval. And better if I can limit to JSONPath rather than XPath.

Currently I'm managing myself using below like approach over JSON.

```
<property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'ALE1_LON'"/>
<property expression="fn:concat('//content[hotelcode=',$ctx:htlCode,']')" name="hotelContentExpr" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="evaluate($ctx:hotelContentExpr)" name="hotelContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

- WSO2 ESB version : 5.0.0

Comment: Could you find a solution for this? Any idea about using variable inside `json-eval()`?

Answer (score 1):

Please test this solution to solve your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JsonDynamicExpression"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{
    "_id":"INV27_1112",
    "_rev":"5-876038bf65752ce4505e50baea6d5581",
    "content":[
        {
            "hotelcode":"AMB3_LON",
            "hotelname":"Ambassadors Bloomsbury"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALE1_LON",
            "hotelname":"Alexandra"
        },
        {
            "hotelcode":"ALO_LON",
            "hotelname":"Aloft London Excel"
        }
    ]
}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="htlCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="ALO_LON"/>
         <property expression="fn:concat('//content[hotelcode=','&#34;',get-property('htlCode'),'&#34;',']')"
                   name="hotelContentExpr"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="evaluate(get-property('hotelContentExpr'))"/>
            <target type="body"/>
         </enrich>
         <log>
            <property expression="$body" name="Cuerpo////////////////////////////"/>
         </log>
         <loopback/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I can do it with the XPath over JSON as I have mentioned in the latter part of my question. But I'm looking forward for a way on doing it with JSONPath in json-eval function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 6.6.0 EI and this solution works for me:

```
<property name="num" value="0"/>
<!-- To avoid json path compilation faliure at run time concat function is been used -->
<property expression="fn:concat('json-eval($..[', $ctx:num, ':])')" name="jsonPath" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="content" expression="json-eval({$ctx:jsonPath})"/>
</log>
```

I hope help you and another people with different EI versions